# Unitary reflection mapping $\vec{u}$ to $\vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, reflection, unitary-matrices

I am trying to give the $(2\times 2)$ unitary reflection which maps the vector $\vec{u}$ to the vector $\vec{v}$. We know that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ obviously have length $1$. I was wondering if anyone can help me out computing this matrix or proving its existence. I have tried working with the image of a reflection: $$S_{\vec{a},\lambda}(\vec{u})=\vec{u}-(1-\lambda)\frac{\vec{u}\bullet\vec{a}}{\vec{a}\bullet\vec{a}}\,\vec{a}$$
A hint is given that $\vec{a}$ should be $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$, however, if this is the case then from my computations I have that $\lambda$ should be $\vec{u}\bullet\vec{v}$ and thus this inner product should satisfy $|\vec{u}\bullet\vec{v}|=1$. I was wondering if any of you has any idea if there is another reflection which does not need the inner product of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$  to have an absolute value of $1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not following your working. Why should $|\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}| = 1$? Most unit length vector pairs do not satisfy this.

Comment: I calculated that when we assume $\vec{a}=\vec{u}-\vec{v}$, this finally comes down to $\lambda=\vec{u}\bullet\vec{v}$. Because the reflection is unitary, the eigenvalues should have absolute value $1$. And indeed, there are lots of vectors not satisfying this, therefore I was looking for another value of $\vec{a}$, but I did not really know how.

Comment: You say they give a hint: which is your source ? I need some context.

Comment: The source of the hint could be wrong. This is part of proving that every unitary $(2\times 2)$-matrix can be written as a product of two unitary reflections.

Comment: How do we know that $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are unit vectors? Only $\lVert u\rVert=\lVert v\rVert$ is necessary for the reflection to exist.

Comment: I don’t understand what the parameter $\lambda$ is doing for you. You could just as well write $\vec u+\mu\vec a$ since the second term is just an arbitrary scalar multiple of $\vec a$.

Answer (score 1):

For the reflection to exist, we need only have $\lVert\vec u\rVert=\lVert\vec v\rVert$; there’s no particular reason that these should be unit vectors.

Assuming that $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are linearly independent, if you imagine what this looks like in $\mathbb R^2$, it should become clear that the reflector must be the angle bisector of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, which is spanned by $\vec u+\vec v$. A normal to this line is the other diagonal of the rhombus defined by the two vectors, $\vec u-\vec v$, hence the hint. Using a standard formula, $$\vec u - 2{\vec u\cdot\vec a \over \vec a\cdot\vec a}\vec a = \vec u - 2{\vec u\cdot(\vec u-\vec v) \over (\vec u-\vec v)\cdot(\vec u-\vec v)}(\vec u-\vec v).$$ Since $\vec u\cdot\vec u=\vec v\cdot\vec v$, the right-hand side reduces to $\vec u-(\vec u-\vec v)=\vec v$.

I’m not really sure what the parameter $\lambda$ in $S_{\vec a,\lambda}(\vec u)$ really does for you, since the second term is just an arbitrary scalar multiple of $\vec a$, so could just as well have been written as $\mu\vec a$. However, starting from that expression and using $\vec a=\vec u-\vec v$, $S_{\vec a,\lambda}(\vec u)=\vec v$ reduces to the condition $$\lambda = {\vec u\cdot\vec v - \vec v\cdot\vec v \over \vec u\cdot\vec u - \vec u\cdot\vec v}.$$ If we also have $\lVert u\rVert = \lVert v\rVert$, then $\lambda=-1$, consistent with the usual formula for reflection in the hyperplane with normal $\vec a$.